# Centripetal Component of Weight Incorrect Understanding?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image: Figure P6.42]

In this figure I see that apparently the centripetal component of a downward $mg$ is apparently $mg \sin (68\deg)$ rather than what I would assume to be $mg / \sin (68\deg)$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a lesson in trigonometry.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, somehow the trig on these things keeps messing with me. I picture it wrong in my mind and can't get away from that.

Comment: My suggestion is that you  start any such problem by drawing a (free body) diagram.